# function call issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to call a function however I get the error that "JavaScript runtime error: 'a' is undefined". I cannot change remove "$(" as it would ruin my other code and I need to be able to get var n inside function a.

```
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
<input type="button" onclick="a()" name="add" value="Add input field" />

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function a ()  { 
  var n = document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, why would you use `document.getElementById()`? If you are not using jQuery there is no reason to wrap `var n`, because that won't do anything.

Comment: `'a' is undefined` because function `a` is out of your calling scope.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your `script` in the head rather than the `body` since your are making use of the jQuery's DOM ready handler anyway.

Also, you should probably extract the named function expression.

```
<script>
    function a() {
        var n = document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
    }
    $(a);
</script>
```

Comment: @PHPglue Well it's better to put them in the `head` since you have no advantages in putting it in the body in this case. The DOM ready handler will make sure it gets executed **only** when the DOM is ready anyway. You put scripts in the `body` when there's a valuable advantage only.

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag, on the Question. Maybe we should ask the inquirer before we assume that. Additionally, that comment is incorrect, because this code would have to be inside the function argument of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: it doesn't work still. in the body/header

Comment: @user2138160 Try extracting the named function expression.

Comment: There is a slight advantage to putting it in the `body`: if the script is at the end of the `body`, the rest of the page will load and can be interacted with before the script has loaded, whereas if the script is first it *must* finish loading before the rest of the page can be loaded.

Comment: @icktoofay Well with an inline script of that size it doesn't have any  noticeable impact.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function to the main function of jQuery, jQuery binds this function to be executed when the DOM has finished loading, but this function isn't accesible in global scope.

If you have using jQuery already you can try with something like this:

```
<script>
    function a(){
          var n = $("#searchTxt").val();
    }
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although answers above has solved main issue, but I don't like any JavaScript in HTML at all, not even the call.
Can I suggest the following edit

```
$(function a() {
    $("input[name='add']").on("click", function() {
        var n = $("#searchTxt").val();
    });
});
```

This serves following purposes -

1. You can safely invoke all your scripts after the HTML and CSS loads
   (recommended).
2. Binds the event to element only if it's present and loaded, falls
   back without any error.
3. Doesn't depend on any scope defined, so you'll never get function
   not defined issue.
4. Isolate the JavaScript from HTML completely (just a choice, not
   mandatory).